# NodeJS and Firebase/Firestore track time and update automatically

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so the functionality I'm trying to create is the user gives me a date eg 06/28/2020 and on 07/28/2020 I'll:

1. send them a notification
2. change the date I was storing from 06/28/2020 to 7/28/2020
3. start tracking for 08/28/2020 to repeat 1 & 2.

And I want to do this automatically. I can do the notification but I'm stuck on how to keep track of the date automatically every day to compare between today's date and the end date which is the 28th of next month and make the changes. Does firebase or nodejs have some feature/package to do this behind the scene without any external events after the user has input the end date?

Right now I can get the dates from firestore and compare it with today's date but ONLY when I have an event like when I go to my profile page. I can also update the date for next month using dateJS. But if I don't go to my page it won't trigger the function. I want to make it automatic and store it somewhere where it doesn't require a user's interaction to trigger it but happens automatically.

Note: The date can be different based on user input so it's not a fixed date. And I'm using NodeJS and firebase for my project.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Firestore does not have that functionallity alone, however, you could use Cloud Functions and Cloud Tasks to do that, here is a [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) that explains in details how you can do that. Let me know if this answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a cloud function that runs every 24 hours using pubsub. You can then get the current date using something like

```
const currentDate = new Date();
```

You can then check if that day is today, by checking if the timestamp in firestore is between now and 24 hours in the future. I would advice using the moment dependency for that. You could do something like:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const tomorrow = moment(currentDate).add(24, 'hours');
if(yourDate > currentDate && yourDate < tomorrow){
    // send notification

    // update to next month
    const nextMonth = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'month');
    db.collection(path).doc(docId).update({
        yourDate: nextMonth,
    });
}
```

Note that this is pseudo code, I haven't fully tested it but I have used a similar technique in the past. This should do the trick for you I think